# Target KitKat MR2 (4.4.3)?

Tags: android

I have a piece of code (actually a library I'm including) that only functions correctly using KitKat MR2 (4.4.3).

The other MR seem to have to their own API versions in Build.VERSION_CODES, but I can't find any way to target 4.4.3 and above using the SDK_INT. Should I just use the incremental String field and do a String comparison?

```
// the "easy" (wrong) way
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= BUILD.VERSION_CODES.KIT_KAT) { // but that includes 4.4, 4.4.1, and 4.4.2!

}

// the "hard" way
if(compareVersionCodes(BUILD.VERSION.RELEASE, "4.4.3") > 0) { // implement some comparison function for the version codes instead

}
```

Is targeting KIT_KAT acceptable -- meaning is this something like version 14 vs 15 where everyone automatically gets the higher version?

Comment: I'm curious what you could be doing that needs so specific a version, and if you wouldn't be better off looking for a way to fix that.  But no, I don't think its safe to assume every kit kat device will be updated to mr2.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's a Bluetooth LE scanning library. Prior to 4.4.3, doing a BLE scan would cause the Bluetooth Service to crash periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find any way to target 4.4.3 and above using the SDK_INT

The API levels are for changes in binary compatibility -- stuff like new classes, new methods, etc. They aren't for bug fixes, other than to the extent such fixes break binary compatibility.

> Should I just use the incremental String field and do a String comparison?

That's not awesome, but unless there's some way you can interrogate the Bluetooth LE APIs to see whether or not you're on a malfunctioning device, you may need to go this route. However, later this year, I'd set up the check algorithm to be more like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.WHATEVER_THEY_CALL_L ||
  (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KIT_KAT && getPatchLevel()>=3)) {
     // do your thing
}
```

where `getPatchLevel()` tries to use `RELEASE` to find the patch level and fails gracefully if `RELEASE` is not of the form X.Y.Z. This approach will handle both the 4.4.3/4.4.4 scenarios and whatever the numbering is for the next Android version.